# Guardar como variable consulta SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

¿Como puedo obtener el ID de una tabla según la sesión con la que se logueo el usuario y así pasarlo a una variable?

Por ejemplo la tabla de usuarios es:

```
|ID   | username    | datelog  |  ID_Personal | pass |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1    | pedro       |2017-07-15|  80.160.487  |123456|
|2    | pablo       |2017-07-12|  75.754.489  |987123|
```

Probé con algo así: `Session["Username"] = User.Identity.Name;`

Y me trae el nombre de usuario en este caso si inició sesion con el `username pedro` y el `pass 123456` me devuelve pedro, pero lo que quiero obtener es el `ID_Personal` de pedro osea `80.160.487`.

Lo que pretendo lograr es que el usuario pueda editar sus datos personales que están en otra tabla llamada "Perfil" usando para esto un `FormView` y le de clic en editar y usar el update para editarlos, ya todo eso funciona solo que no se como relacionar el `FormView` a la variable de usuario que inicia sesión.

Nota: Uso SQL server, por si de algo sirve.

He probado sin éxito algo así:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Username"] = User.Identity.Name;

        int CliNif;
        using (var con =  new SqlConnection("Promtech_CS")
        {
        con.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CLI_NIF FROM Users WHERE Username=@Username", con);
        CliNif = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Ejemplo de la lógica de lo que busco porque creo que está enredada la pregunta:

```
Session["Username"] = User.Identity.Name;

var Consulta = (SELECT ID_Personal FROM Users WHERE Username=@Username)

<asp:Formview>.......</asp:Formview>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1">
SelectCommand="SELECT CLI_ID, CLI_Apellido1, CLI_Apellido2, CLI_Nombre, CLI_Tratamiento, CLI_Nacimiento, CLI_Edad FROM CLIENTES WHERE CLI_NIF = @Consulta"
...
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: No seria mas fácil seleccionar 'ID_Personal', es lo que veo mas lógico o me equivoco

Comment: El problema radica en que son tablas separadas en diferentes bases de datos, no se como hacerlo en ese caso por eso  busco tomar la sesion de la tabla 1 y llevarla hasta buscar en la tabla 2 que tienen en comun el ID_personal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu ejemplo no estas pasando el parámetro a la consulta, en tu caso seria algo asi:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Session["Username"] = User.Identity.Name;
    int CliNif;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        string selectQuery = "SELECT CLI_NIF FROM Users WHERE Username=@Username";
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["Username"].ToString() );
        CliNif = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // cLogger.Error(String.Format("{0} - {1}", ClassName, ex.Message));
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya decía que algo me faltaba, aunque, me arroja error de: No se puede usar la variable local 'con' antes de declararla, ¿acaso no está ya declarada ?

Comment: No recomendaría usar ese código en el Load de la pagina, ponlo en un método que se ejecute después de la carga. Si depuras, fíjate que 'con' ya este instanciada y no este en Null

Comment: La verdad compadre no entendí nada de nada, verás estoy tratando de aprender esto de asp.net de solo tutoriales no soy universitario, y aunque he leido no comprendo a que te refieres. :(

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, intenta con eso. En connectionString debe estar tu cadena de conexion

Comment: Entre parcial de tu código y un revuelto de lo que he encontrado en internet creo que logre obtener la label el valor que necesito, pero me queda la intriga de porque dices que no se recomienda en el load de la página?

Comment: Por que el código se ejecutara varias veces. Mas informacion puedes encontrar aquí: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx Pero indicarte que puedes usar un condicionante **IsPostBack** para evitar la carga múltiple

Comment: Ya veo... muchas gracias por la aclaración compa!